# Replace placholders in CSV with actual values - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I've a template CSV file that has placeholders like `{$NAME}`
Now I want to replace all those placeholders with actual value.

I'm using Laravel, but that shouldn't matter.

Currently doing something like this:

```php
$templateCSV = Storage::get('quote.intake.form.template.csv'); // it reads the file contents
 
$vars = [ // define the placeholders with actual values
   '{$AGENT_NAME}'  => $agent['name'],
   '{$AGENT_PHONE}'  => $agent['phone'],
];

$newCSV = strtr($templateCSV, $vars); // finally replace those placeholders.

Storage::put("my-new-csv.csv", $newCSV); // saves the new CSV
```

It works, but I don't think this is the proper way of doing this. cause when a value has "," it will break the csv structure.

I'm sure there must be some better way of doing this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Read line by line using `fgetcsv`, loop over the resulting column data array and do you replacements within each value, write back using `fputcsv`.

Comment: If Laravel doesn't have its own `fputcsv()` helper method which allows proper quoting of row values, then don't use Laravel for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your values in double quotes but this means you need to escape double quotes within the values:

```
$sanitiseCsv = fn ($value) => '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $value).'"';

$vars = [ // define the placeholders with actual values
   '{$AGENT_NAME}'  => $sanitiseCsv($agent['name']),
   '{$AGENT_PHONE}'  => $sanitiseCsv($agent['phone']),
];
```

Note: doubling the double quotes seems to be the correct way to escape double quotes in double quoted CSV values.